# How to change Bootstrap dropdown selected item with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change Bootstrap dropdown item select with jQuery? I'm newbie in jQuery. I put dropdown list data from database with foreach loop. and I've a button. that have "id" and "value". When I click on that button, i want to change my bootstrap dropdown 'li' selected item to it button's "vaule" and "id".Please help me.

```
<div class="dropdown" align="right">
    <input type="button" id="select_staff" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" value="<?php echo $cur_admin_name ?> ▼">
    <ul id="admin_cal_list" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
    <input type="hidden" id="admin_id" class="form-control">
        <?php foreach ($admin_name as $admin_list): ?>
            <li id="<?php echo $admin_list["interview_plan_staff_id"]; ?>"><a href="#"><?php echo $admin_list["interview_plan_staff_name"]; ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this..

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
  var selText = $(this).text();
  console.log( selText);
  $(this).parents('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-toggle').val(selText);
});
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/EuFKxaQ2bO

Comment: Your answer is for Dropdown click? But I want is on Button click change the dropdown value and id. Is that it? I'm noob. please explain me. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I tested it on your link. But i want is not like that. Thanks you for your answer. I want is, there are both dropdown and button. The button has value and id inside. When click on button, then add that button's value to dropdown as selected.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the use case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I 100% understand what you are trying to do. For clarity, you want the li to change to the button's id and value? If so try this:

```
    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
    document.getElementById("admin_cal_list").innerHTML = $(".dropdown-toggle").attr("id") + " " + $(".dropdown-toggle").attr("value");
});
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/UphW5kYtwE